# Spring Batch Reader for distributed DB2 database

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to write a job using Spring batch framework. Job needs to get data from a clustered db2 database, call some logic on each fetched record and then store transformed data in same db ( different table than from where it was read).  I am trying to write `step1` as below,

```
@Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
            ItemReader<RemittanceVO> reader, ItemWriter<RemittanceClaimVO> writer,
            ItemProcessor<RemittanceVO, RemittanceClaimVO> processor) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<RemittanceVO, RemittanceClaimVO> chunk(100).reader(reader)
                .processor(processor).writer(writer).build();
    }
```

Currently, I face two challenges due to database being DB2 and being clustered,

**1.**

SQLs provided for meta data at -
    `/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-db2.sql` doesn't work for
    distributed DB2. It fails on command , `constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY)` .

Queries written in this file can be
    tweaked to distributed db2 or I can create tables manually too  but I am
    not sure if I should create tables manually? if that will have some
    further complications?

I need all these tables because I wanted to used Spring batch for its `PAUSE` , `RESTART` functionalities.

**2.**

We need to fire all SELECT queries on DB2
    with `READ ONLY WITH UR`    [SO
    question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617273/adding-with-ur-or-any-other-prefix-in-query-being-generated-by-jdbcpagingitemr).
    If we don't run queries with this keyword, db can get locked.

Problem in point # 2 is that I can't use in built reader classes of Spring Batch (`JdbcPagingItemReader` etc )as those doesn't support this db2 specific keyword.

By reading useless simple examples on Internet that explain advantages of this framework, I thought that I will be up and running in a very short period but it looks I have to write own query provider classes, research meta data sqls and what not if db happens to be DB2 and distributed.

Has anybody implemented similar job for distributed Db2 database and guide me on above points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, to solve point # 1 , I will create tables manually since I have confirmed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073436/dropping-of-meta-data-tables-by-spring-batch) that tables will not get dropped automatically so recreation will not be needed. One time manual activity should be enough.

and I will solve point # 2 by specifying isolation levels at transaction level so `WITH UR` in SELECT queries will not be needed,

```
@Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Bean
        public TransactionTemplate transactionTemplateUR(){
            TransactionTemplate txnTemplate = new TransactionTemplate();
            txnTemplate.setIsolationLevelName("ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED");
            txnTemplate.setTransactionManager(txnManager);
            return txnTemplate;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager txnManager(DataSource dataSource){
            DataSourceTransactionManager txnManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
            txnManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
            return txnManager;
        }
```

Comment: Your solution for point #2 isn't good, because you will get inconsistent data if rollback occurs. So you should use org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.Db2PagingQueryProvider as starting point and modify it for your requirements.